# Foreign key conflict

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

//EDMX File
http://pastebin.com/btTCRMf7

I have 2 tables `Customers` and `Sites`

```
//Site
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public int CityID { get; set; }
public int CountryID { get; set; }
public int EncodedBy { get; set; }
public System.DateTime DateEncoded { get; set; }

public virtual City City { get; set; }
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

//Customer
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public int CityID { get; set; }
public int CountryID { get; set; }
public int CreditTermID { get; set; }
public int EncodedBy { get; set; }
public System.DateTime DateEncoded { get; set; }
public virtual City City { get; set; }
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
public virtual CreditTerm CreditTerm { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }

//Country
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }

//City
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }


//SiteModel
private static IQueryable<Site> Build(this DbSet<Site> query)
{
    return query.Include("User").Include("City").Include("Country").Include("Customer");
}

public static Site Find(int siteID)
{
    using (DragonRentalsEntities context = new DragonRentalsEntities(new ConfigurationManager().ConnectionString))
    {
        Site result = context.Sites.Build().SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == siteID);
        return result;
    }
}

public static Site Update(Site _updatedSite)
{
    using (DragonRentalsEntities context = new DragonRentalsEntities(new ConfigurationManager().ConnectionString))
    {
        context.Sites.Attach(_updatedSite);
        context.Entry(_updatedSite).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Find(_updatedSite.ID);
    }
}

Site test = SiteModel.Find(1);
test.City = null;
test.CityID = 1;
test.Country = null;
test.CountryID = 1;

test.Customer = null;
test.CustomerID = 1;

SiteModel.Update(test);
```

i am getting `A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.`

however, adding `test.Customer.City = null;` before updating the object would work. it seems like Customer.City and Site.City is conflicting. can somebody explain why? or any workaround?

Comment: What is `.Build()` doing?

Comment: Build() is just eager loading the foreign keys, bunch of includes("...")

Comment: Why do you include the navigation properties and then set it to `null`  afterwards (`test.City = null`, etc.), but the foreign key properties to another value (`test.CityID = 1`, etc.)? The procedure is strange. Are the foreign keys nullable?

Comment: @Slauma if i don't set it to null, i won't be able to attach them in the update method, the same error would be triggered

Comment: show the actual entity classes

Comment: There are two entities commented as //Site

Comment: @ilmatte my bad, it should be City

Comment: please post some working example to reproduce the issue, or at least include OnModelCreating (to get the same WillCascadeOnDelete calls) and   Build() method body to load exactly the same data set.

Comment: @PashaPash i have updated my question. the datacontext is generated from my database. OnModelCreating just throws `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`

Comment: the code above works for me (if Site.User is omitted). not sure why test.Customer.City = null helps. test.Customer is already null, so this workaround should throw NullReferenceException.

Comment: Please show code for `Build()`

Comment: @Moho Build() is posted already.

Comment: @PashaPash i am also wondering about that...

Comment: Can you post the EDMX?

Comment: @Moho http://pastebin.com/btTCRMf7

Comment: I can't reproduce, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I can explain why. Include persists entity to load all the include objects.So our site object has all references to your clusses (City, Country,User Customer). I think that is the problem. The solve can be to load only site object:

```
Site result = context.Sites.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == siteID);
```

so it would load only ids of the site object. Than you can load refered objects by it ids in runtime where you need.

I think it is because when you use include, you operate objects and collections of objects  dbContext tracks this changes and  saves them when you call

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

a bit refactored code btw:

```
public static Site Update(Site _updatedSite)
  {
     using (DragonRentalsEntities context = new DragonRentalsEntities(new ConfigurationManager().ConnectionString))
     {

          if (context.Entry(_updatedSite).State == EntityState.Detached)
               context.Entry(_updatedSite).State = EntityState.Modified;// attaches  entity and marks it as modified if it is detached

          context.SaveChanges();
          return _updatedSite; //after save changes u have the same object as u send in your Update function
    }
  }
```

**Comment answer** 
Slauma if i don't set it to null, i won't be able to attach them in the update method, the same error would be triggered

***Answer:*** 
Because when you include all entities you have got already attached to your context objects.
Btw Include transforms on sql inner join statement so may be your snapshot of db objects doesnt contain City with that ID.